# pooling using Rx JS until all data is processed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

What's the best way to write this short pooling routine using rx.js

```
 1. call the function this.dataService.getRowsByAccountId(id) to return  Observable<Row[]> from back-end
 2. send the received data to this function this.refreshGrid(data);
 3. if one of items in the data meet this criteria r.stillProcessing==true
 4. then wait 2 seconds and start again from step-1
 5. if another call was made to this routine and there is a pending timer scheduled. Don't schedule another one because i don't want multiple timers running.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be using [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html)

I don't know if this will work out of the box with your code, but according to your comment try to tweak this.

```
this.dataService.getRowsByAccountId(id)
 .pipe(
  tap((data: Row[]) => this.refreshGrid(data)),
  map((data: Row[]) => {
    if (data.some((r: Row) => r.stillProcessing === true) {
      //error will be picked up by retryWhen
      throw r.Name; //(or something else)
    }
    return r;
  }),
  retryWhen(errors =>
    errors.pipe(
      //log error message
      tap((r: Row) => console.log(`Row ${r} is still processing!`)),
      //restart in 2 seconds
      delayWhen(() => timer(2000))
    )
  ).subscribe();
);
```